# Game with Javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm new with javascript and i want to learn it so i thought i just ask it.
i have a snake game in html using javascript and i want to speed up the game.
now i have

```
var level = 160;
```

and to speed up the game i need to decrease the number with 30 when i hit a button.
but it won't work.

i have:

```
function difficult() {

 changeVariable("level")=160-30
 }
```

and

```
<button onclick="difficult()">More difficult</button>
```

i think it's totaly wrong what i'm doing so i hope you guys could help me.

thanks

***edit***

what i'm trying to is: i have a variable for the level speed. and i want at least 2 buttons to make the game harder or easier. so i want with a click on the button to decrease or increase the var with 30.

Comment: what does `changeVariable` do?

Comment: And, what about your system prevents code like `level = 160 - 30;` from working?

Comment: You can't assign to a function call like that. Did you try `level = 130`?

Comment: Instead of `changeVariable("level")=160-30`, just use `level = level - 30;`

Comment: i want on every click the number decrease with 30, so that they can make it harder or easier

Comment: So, I think you need to provide the code for `changeVariable`.  That's obviously the place where you're changing the variable.  And if you can't use the suggestion from @Ian, then I'm assuming you have some other logic in there.  Please post that function's code so we can help you.

Answer (score 6):

You'd probably be better off setting up the function that changes the difficulty to take a param, so you can re-use it anywhere.

```
var level = 160;
function ResetDifficulty() { level = 160; }
function AdjustDifficulty(amt) {
    level += amt;
}
```

then you could create several links that call the same function with various values, rather than creating a bunch of different functions.

```
<button onclick="javascript: AdjustDifficulty(-30)">Less Difficult</button>
<button onclick="javascript: ResetDifficulty()">Normal Difficulty</button>
<button onclick="javascript: AdjustDifficulty(30)">More Difficult</button>
```

Comment: i tried it but there was no change in speed. so like this it didn't work.

Comment: then you need to look at whatever code is using the `level` variable to determine the game speed, after verifying that the `level` variable is correctly updated after you click on one of your buttons.

Comment: @Moreno__R His code is correct and should work depending on your current code, can you please post all of your current code and a jsfiddle of it would also be helpful.